# Delete android window after timeout

Tags: android, window, timeout

I was looking through the [WindowManager's API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) but I couldn't find a way to make the window disappear after a certain period of time. My desired functionality is to initially make the window pop up, wait until timeout and then disappear/delete itself.

Comment: From what?  An activity?

Comment: From a WindowManager after setting up LayoutParams and calling .addView(view, param).

Comment: So you just want to remove a view that you previously added?

Comment: After a timeout I want the view to be removed, yes. I also want the view to be register events so the timeout should not interfere with that but that's more of a side to my initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewManager.removeView(View v)`

Comment: Is a question an answer? ;)

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. It is somewhat incomplete but it did add some direction as to where I wanted to go. If it the reason was it was phrased as a question, please try to edit the answer instead of downvoting as that is why it is there for. This answer actually helped me somewhat.

Comment: I tried to get involved in stack overflow a few months back to no avail, and it seems I'm not getting off to a good start here either.

Comment: Look up a bunch of popular questions/answers to help you out with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding and using this method:

```
/**
 * Simple method that will take any view class and remove it from it's parent
 * @param viewToRemove the view you want to remove from its parent
 */
private void removeViewFromItsParent(View viewToRemove){
    if (viewToRemove == null || viewToRemove.getParent() == null){
        Log.w("tag", "view or parent is null, no-operation");
        return;
    }
    ViewGroup viewGroupParent = (ViewGroup) viewToRemove.getParent();
    viewGroupParent.removeView(viewToRemove);
}
```

Something like: `removeViewFromItsParent(view)`;

More info here about ViewGroup including its subclasses and what methods you can use (there are a few remove calls that do slightly different things) : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                yourParentView.removeView(childView);
            }
        }, TIME);
```